# How to specify `ON CONFLICT` in the table definition?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to specify in a postgreSQL table definition what to do on conflict like "unique constraint violated"?

In my case I simply want to ignore the conflict violating primary key constraint. If new item of the same primary key is added, lets just not add it or replace with the new one (both are good). I want to treat database as a set, so I thought that - if possible - it'd be good to have this specified already in table definitions and not in insert queries.

In other words: How to define the relation in a way that the "on conflict" part in the expression:

`insert into transaction values (id, amount) on conflict (id) do nothing`

is implicit in every insert query. Possible?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: You could create a trigger for that purpose.